# Delete specific rows based in conditions on rows from a dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to delete specific rows based in conditions on rows from a Pandas dataframe.

For example, since I have several currency pairs at the same time, I intend to select only one of the currencies of the same time.

This is the priority: EUR, USD, GBP, CHF.

```
currency    timebuy buyprice
CNHUSD  2021-01-05 08:30:00 0,00005073
CNHGBP  2021-01-05 08:30:00 1,588
ZARGBP  2021-01-07 05:15:00 0,2727
ZARUSD  2021-01-07 05:15:00 300
ZAREUR  2021-01-07 13:00:00 0,1936
ZARCHF  2021-01-07 13:00:00 0,0000052
JPYCHF  2021-01-13 06:00:00 0,0002222
JPYUSD  2021-01-13 06:00:00 8
JPYGBP  2021-01-13 06:00:00 8
```

[image]

to

```
currency    timebuy buyprice
CNHUSD  2021-01-05 08:30:00 0,00005073
ZAREUR  2021-01-07 13:00:00 0,1936
JPYUSD  2021-01-13 06:00:00 8
```

[image]

Comment: Hi again, Fábio :) Will you please post your tables as text in the question? I can't copy/paste from images.

Comment: Sorry there was a mistake, now its correct! thanks Richardec

Comment: So what's the logic here?

Comment: i have several currency pairs at the same timestamp.
I just want one of them in each timestamp.
It it as *EUR is my first choice, if not i prefer *USD, GDP, CHF...

Comment: Should the output also include a row for `ZARUSD, 2021-01-07 05:15:00, 300`?

Comment: Are you grouping by the first 3 chars of `currency`, or by each unique value of `timebuy`?

Comment: @FábioSilvério did any of the answers work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `groupby` and `reindex`:

```
# Hard-code your priority for the second currency in each pair
pri = ['EUR', 'USD', 'GBP', 'CHF']

# Create a new column for the second currency of each pair
df['2ndcurr'] = df['currency'].str[-3:]


# Group by time and second currency,
# Sort inner level (1) of resulting MultiIndex to match priority,
# Group by the outer level (0),
# Get the first row of each group,
# Reset timebuy from index into its own column

(df.set_index(['timebuy', '2ndcurr'])
   .reindex(pri, level=1)
   .groupby(level=0)
   .first()
   .reset_index())

               timebuy currency    buyprice
0  2021-01-05 08:30:00   CNHUSD  0,00005073
1  2021-01-07 05:15:00   ZARUSD         300
2  2021-01-07 13:00:00   ZAREUR      0,1936
3  2021-01-13 06:00:00   JPYUSD           8
```

Answer (score 1):

For a priority list like this, it's easiest to work with numbers. So, you can create a nice numeric mapping from your priority list, and use it to pick rows:

```
priority = ['EUR', 'USD', 'GBP', 'CHF']
mapping = {p: i for i, p in enumerate(priority)}
indexes = df['currency'].str[-3:].map(mapping).groupby(df['currency'].str[:3]).idxmin().sort_values()
selected = df.loc[indexes]
```

Output:

```
>>> selected
  currency             timebuy    buyprice
0   CNHUSD 2021-01-05 08:30:00  0,00005073
4   ZAREUR 2021-01-07 13:00:00      0,1936
7   JPYUSD 2021-01-13 06:00:00           8
```

One-liner:

```
priority = ['EUR', 'USD', 'GBP', 'CHF']
filtered = df.loc[df['currency'].str[-3:].map({p: i for i, p in enumerate(priority)}).groupby(df['currency'].str[:3]).idxmin().sort_values()]
```

If you want to group by each timestamp instead of the first 3 letters of `currency`, group by `df['timestamp']` instead of `df['currency'].str[:3]`, i.e.:

```
indexes = df['currency'].str[-3:].map(mapping).groupby(df['timestamp']).idxmin().sort_values()
                                                     # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```